# what is the resource_type_id in metadatavalue?

Tags: java, dspace

I am new to dspace. I am retrieving values from dspace metadatavalue table. One think I don't understand is resource_type_id in metadatavalue table. Resource_type_id has specific values. It has value 3 for collection name and its description, 0 for bitstreams etc. What do these values stand for?

Comment: So, whats the cuestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in `resource_type_id` columns in the DSpace database tables refer to the constants in the `org.dspace.core.Constants` class: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/core/Constants.java#L20

```
/** Type of bitstream objects */
public static final int BITSTREAM = 0;

/** Type of bundle objects */
public static final int BUNDLE = 1;

/** Type of item objects */
public static final int ITEM = 2;

/** Type of collection objects */
public static final int COLLECTION = 3;

/** Type of community objects */
public static final int COMMUNITY = 4;

/** DSpace site type */
public static final int SITE = 5;

/** Type of eperson groups */
public static final int GROUP = 6;

/** Type of individual eperson objects */
public static final int EPERSON = 7;
```